# How to add text values in bar plot seaborn python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, visualization

i want visualyze with seaborn and add the text. this my code:

```
# barplot price by body-style
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,8))
g = data[['body-style','price']].groupby(by = 'body- 
style').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='price')
x = g['body-style']
y = g['price']
ok = sns.barplot(x,y, ci = None)
ax.set_title('Price By Body Style')
def autolabel(rects):
   for idx,rect in enumerate(ok):
       height = rect.get_height()
       g.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 0.2*height,
             g['price'].unique().tolist()[idx],
             ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
autolabel(ok)
```

but i go error:

[image]

Comment: what does it means autolabel(ax.patched)? where can i write it?

Comment: @JohanC i still wrong code

Comment: i finish try it and got an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a few changes:

- As you already created the `ax`, you need `sns.barplot(..., ax=ax)`.
- `autolabel()` needs to be called with the list of bars as argument. With seaborn you get this list via `ax.patches`.
- `for idx,rect in enumerate(ok):` shouldn't use `ok` but `rects`.
- You can't use `g.text`. `g` is a dataframe and doesn't have a `.text` function. You need `ax.text`.
- Using `g['price'].unique().tolist()[idx]` as the text to print doesn't have any relationship with the plotted bars. You could use `height` instead.

Here is some test code with toy data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
g = data[['body-style','price']].groupby(by = 'body-style').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='price')
x = g['body-style']
y = g['price']
# x = list('abcdefghij')
# y = np.random.randint(20, 100, len(x))

sns.barplot(x, y, ci=None, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Price By Body Style')

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., 0.2 * height,
                height,
                ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90, color='white')

autolabel(ax.patches)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: You can change the fontsize of the text via a parameter to `ax.text`: `ax.text(..., fontsize=14)`.